# Multiple Producer Multiple Consumer lock-free (or even wait-free) queue

Tags: .net, multithreading, queue, consumer, producer

I'm searching for documentation on how to write MP/MC queue to be lock-free or even wait-free. I'm using .Net 4.0. Found a lot of C++ code, but I'm not very familiar with memory models, so there is a big chance I will introduce some bugs while porting to C#.

Comment: This thread might be a start: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.programming.threads/browse_thread/thread/87b343bf5cd1dc46

Comment: There is an excellent Java book on the topic: Java Concurreny in Practice. All the code samples are available on their [website][1], however, without the book the code might be difficult to understand if you are not familiar with the Java concurrency framework.

  [1]: http://www.javaconcurrencyinpractice.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you think you need lock-free queue? Have you tried using [`ConcurrentQueue<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx), possibly enclosed within a [`BlockingCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx)?

Writing multi-threaded code is hard. Writing lock-free code is even harder and you shouldn't do it yourself unless you really have to.

Comment: I'm writing general-purpose subsystem, so I just want to make it as good as possible.

Comment: @adontz, in that case, you should make your system extendable: you provide some implementation of concurrent queue that's good enough in most cases, but let your users write their own if they need it.

Comment: Unfortunately (for me), primary use case is a high load, so lock-free is not more than "good enough". I'm not expected to implement a wait-free queue by default, however lock based solution is unacceptable. I'm not an enemy of myself, It is really needed to implement at least a lock-free queue.

Comment: @adontz, do you need your queue to be really FIFO? If not and you expect that often the same thread both produces and consumes items, you can use `ConcurrentBag<T>`. In any case, all those collections try to use locking as little as possible, so I'm not sure your solution is going to be much better.

Answer (score 3):

As an option to consider, there's an algorithm of [the bounded Multiple Producer Multiple Consumer queue by Dmitry Vyukov](http://www.1024cores.net/home/lock-free-algorithms/queues/bounded-mpmc-queue). I've ported the algorithm to .NET, you can find [the sources on github](https://github.com/alexandrnikitin/MPMCQueue.NET). It's very fast.

The enqueue algorithm:

```
public bool TryEnqueue(object item)
{
    do
    {
        var buffer = _buffer; // prefetch the buffer pointer
        var pos = _enqueuePos; // fetch the current position where to enqueue the item
        var index = pos & _bufferMask; // precalculate the index in the buffer for that position
        var cell = buffer[index]; // fetch the cell by the index
        // If its sequence wasn't touched by other producers
        // and we can increment the enqueue position
        if (cell.Sequence == pos && Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _enqueuePos, pos + 1, pos) == pos)
        {
            // write the item we want to enqueue
            Volatile.Write(ref buffer[index].Element, item);
            // bump the sequence
            buffer[index].Sequence = pos + 1;
            return true;
        }

        // If the queue is full we cannot enqueue and just return false
        if (cell.Sequence < pos)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // repeat the process if other producer managed to enqueue before us
    } while (true);
}
```

The dequeue algorithm:

```
public bool TryDequeue(out object result)
{
    do
    {
        var buffer = _buffer; // prefetch the buffer pointer
        var bufferMask = _bufferMask; // prefetch the buffer mask
        var pos = _dequeuePos; // fetch the current position from where we can dequeue an item
        var index = pos & bufferMask; // precalculate the index in the buffer for that position
        var cell = buffer[index]; // fetch the cell by the index
        // If its sequence was changed by a producer and wasn't changed by other consumers
        // and we can increment the dequeue position
        if (cell.Sequence == pos + 1 && Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _dequeuePos, pos + 1, pos) == pos)
        {
            // read the item
            result = Volatile.Read(ref cell.Element);
            // update for the next round of the buffer
            buffer[index] = new Cell(pos + bufferMask + 1, null);
            return true;
        }

        // If the queue is empty return false
        if (cell.Sequence < pos + 1)
        {
            result = default(object);
            return false;
        }

        // repeat the process if other consumer managed to dequeue before us
    } while (true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My first go would be with `ConcurrentQueue<T>` but you can abstract your data store away behind an interface so you can easily change implementations. Then benchmark typical scenarios and see where you run into problems. Remember: Premature optimzation is the root of all evil. Design your system so it's not tied to an implementation but to a contract and then you can optimize your implementations all you want.

I had a look at `ConcurrentQueue<T>` with ILSpy and seems to be a lock free implementation at first glance - so good chance it's exactly what your are looking for.

Comment: ConcurrentQueue<T> is just a piece of MPMC queue. It does not help in waiting for new item arrival, notifying of new item arrived.

I think that one AutoResetEvent will be enough for this, was modeling different situations: producers working faster than consumers at some moment, consumers working faster than producer at some moment. False wake up is a problem too, thread should not wake up just to see empty queue. So there are a lot of places to make mistake.

I am generally aware of multithreading, but definitely not a professional in this area.

Comment: @adontz, that's where `BlockingCollection<T>` is going to help you. It takes care of waiting for new items for consumers and waiting until there is free space in the queue, if you choose to limit its size, for producers.